# TYPO3 - Add HTML Font Tag in rte_ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, typo3

The rte_ckeditor removes the font tag added via sourcecode just after switching back to the rendered view. How can i prevent this?

Comment: Did you try to add this in your Yaml file?

# Allow s and u tag
processing:
  allowTags:
    - s
    - yourTag

Sorry, it is impossible to read here...

Answer (score 1):

The [`<font>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) is obsolete. Please use CSS for all styling instead.

In case you need to prepare a design for mails, what you apparently do, you could follow a different approach by adding your `<style>` to the page you want to send via mail and let solutions like the [TYPO3 Mail CSS Inliner](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/mail_css_inliner/) take care of moving your styles inline.

Comment: It's about the Mail Bodytext for Powermail. I want to style the html output a bit, so or i need to add a style attribute or better add the font tag.

Comment: It's always good if you add as much context as possible to your question. In this case styling is indeed very limited but you should go with the `style` attribute.

Comment: i cant even use the stlye attribute in my case.

i am using a table -> tr -> td, and in my td i cant use span tags neither append an style attribute to the td element.

Comment: Could you elaborate as to why you cannot uses span tags inside of td-tags? (I can wrap td content into DIV tags, e.g....)
Also: HtmlArea is uninstalled? Did you check RTE.default.proc...?

Comment: @Tomas I've added a possible solution for styling in mails.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add this in your Yaml file?

## Allow s and u tag

processing:
  allowTags:
    - s
    - yourTag

Comment: yes i added it there:

Full.yaml:

# Allow s and u tag
processing:
  allowTags:
    - s
    - u
    - font

Comment: The standard configuration that comes with TYPO3 has "removeTags: [center, font, link, meta, o:p, sdfield, strike, style, title, u]". So you probably need to overwrite that in your configuration?

Comment: i deleted unter HTMLparser_db: removeTags the font entry, i also added under processing: allowTags the font entry. Nevertheless as matthias wrote, i just have to add a style attribute or a span tag. Both doesnt function either with the standard configuration. Problem is that i am using a table->tr->td and in that td element i need that style.